# Large Neural Networks have zero bias in the bias-variance tradeoff?

Tags: neural-networks, bias

We know that neural networks are universal approximators. That means that they can approximate ANY function (with a large enough number of hidden neurons).

Error can be broken down into two components: bias and variance. Bias is error due to your model's inability to represent the target function.

Since neural networks are universal approximators, there should be no error due to bias. There will only be error due to variance.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Note universal approx ignores training algorithm, whereas using gradient descent,  drop out and other tricks regularise the network ,  limiting the functions that can be learnt

Comment: I don't quite see how my logic is flawed. Gradient descent is a randomized approach. The are no functional limitations to the model itself. Hence, we will have zero bias

Comment: Are you taking in here about networks that have infinitely many parameters and can be trained for infinite about of time, or about real world networks? If the latter, notion of "universal approximator" does not really apply...

Answer (score 0):

It is not about functional limitation of the model, but rather the methods you search in this function families. Given enough hidden unit NN can appromixate any function in some degree, but learning algorithm doesn't guarantee to find the optimum function families that make NN universal approximator.

So in function space, there is certain functions that make the bias zero. These functions are good approximations of the function at the hand. However, function search algorithm (gradient descent) doesn't guarantee you to find these functions.

Comment: So - the bias variance trade-off only applies to models and NOT algorithms?